# Subquery - Group By - SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Ok, tengo dos Queries, El primero solicito los nombres de los clientes y los ordeno alfabeticamente:

```
SELECT Firstname,
       Lastname
  FROM customers
 ORDER BY Firstname
```

En el segun solicito el total de las compras:

```
Select Customerid, Sum (Total) As Total
From invoices
Group by CustomerId
```

Mi objetivo es obtener una tabla donde en lugar de que aparezca el CustomerId, pueda obtener FirstName y LastName.

Segun yo tendria que ser algo asi:

```
SELECT Firstname,
       Lastname
       (
       Select Customerid, Sum (Total) As Total
       From invoices
       Group by CustomerId
       ) As Total
  FROM customers
 ORDER BY Firstname
```

Pero no me arroja resultado alguno asi que solicito de su ayuda.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un `join`

```
SELECT Firstname,Lastname, Sum(i.Total) as Total 
FROM customers c Inner Join invoices i ON c.id=i.CustomerId 
Group By c.id ORDER BY c.Firstname
```